# How do I prevent nested for loops from causing multiple returns of the same value?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to write a program that goes through items in a list. Takes those items apart piece by piece and then assigns a value to them. In this case I am using numbers as my items. I want to assign a value of either prime, even, or other. (Represented as 'p', 'e', or 'o'.)
Example code:

```
testCode = ''
testCodeList = []
prime = ['2','3','5','7']
even = ['4','6','8']
other = ['1','9']
list = ['76']
for item in list:
    for num in item:
        for eve in even:
            if num == eve:
                testCode = testCode + 'e'
            else:
                for pri in prime:
                    if num == pri:
                        testCode = testCode + 'p'
                    else:
                        for othello in other:
                            if num == othello:
                                testCode = testCode + 'o'
                            else:
                                pass
print testCode
```

And here is an example of the output:

> > > pppe

How do I make it only give me 'pe' like I want it too?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you really want the list items to be strings?

Comment: How would this equal 'peo' if you only have '7' and '6'? Are you looking for 'pe'?

Comment: This actually only prints `pppe`.

Comment: my bad, you are correct. typo.

Comment: Your logic looks way too complicated. It sounds like what you want to do is a) For each number in the list b) For each digit in the number c) Is it even? If so, append 'e', otherwise d) is it prime? if so, append 'p' and e) if neither, append 'o'. Try to recode it according to this and see if you get any closer.

Comment: Also, you're not returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

The three inner for loops where you go over the primes, evens and others is where the problem rests. You should do this instead:

```
testCode = ''
testCodeList = []
prime = ['2','3','5','7']
even = ['4','6','8']
other = ['1','9']
list = ['76']
for item in list:
    for num in item:
        if num in even:
            testCode = testCode + 'e'
        elif num in prime:
            testCode = testCode + 'p'
        elif num in other:
            testCode = testCode + 'o'
        else:
            pass
```

Also depending on your objective of this code, you may want to replace the declaration of the `even`, `prime` and `other` lists with functions/commands to check to see if the number is in fact even, prime or other. In other words, for example for the `even` part, you could check to see if the number is divisible by two instead of checking to see if the number exists in the `even` list. This can be done by replacing `if num in even:` with `if int(num) % 2 == 0:`.

Comment: Thanks! this is a big help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a bunch of nested loops if you just want to check for membership. Use the `in` operator.

```
testCode = ''
prime = ['2','3','5','7']
even = ['4','6','8']
other = ['1','9']
lst = ['76']
for item in lst:
    for num in item:
        if num in even:
            testCode += 'e'
        if num in prime:
            testCode += 'p'
        if num in other:
            testCode += 'o'
```

This results in `testCode` being `'pe'` as desired. Note that repeatedly adding to a string is probably not the best way to do things. Consider appending to the `list` you never used, `testCodeList`, instead. Also, naming something `list` means you can't use the built-in function `list()` without extra effort.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I am just a n00b doing python for fun on the side. This is a big help! Thanks!